# Can't get these divs to display inline

Tags: html, css

I have a website located [here](http://dev.mpirebooking.com/).

I am having a hard time displaying some  tags as inline. There are no breaks in the HTML,  and no clear attributes. There's something missing here, but I don't know what.

Basically, I want them set up like this...

[logoimage][slider][logotitle]

I have changed the slider size by percentage, and tried wrapping everything in a new div and adding the "in-line block" attribute.

**Here's my HTML...**

```
<div id="top">

    <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://dev.mpirebooking.com"><img id="logoimage" src="images/logo_mpire_management.png" width="80" height="56" alt="logo"></a></div>   <!-- Logo image -->

        <section id="slideshow">    <!-- Slideshow Start -->
        <div class="html_carousel">
            <div id="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="images/slideshow/sliderimage1.jpg" width="3000" height="783" alt="2 Chainz"/><!-- Replace these images with your own but make sure they are 3000px wide and 783px high or the same ration -->
                </div><!--/slide-->

                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="images/slideshow/sliderimage2.jpg" width="3000" height="783" alt="French Montana"/><!-- Replace these images with your own but make sure they are 3000px wide and 783px high or the same ration -->
                </div><!--/slide-->

                <div class="slide">
                    <img src="images/slideshow/sliderimage3.jpg" width="3000" height="783" alt="2 Pistols"/><!-- Replace these images with your own but make sure they are 3000px wide and 783px high or the same ration -->
                </div><!--/slide-->

                                <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/sliderimage4.jpg" width="3000" height="783" alt="Juicy-J"/><!-- Replace these images with your own but make sure they are 3000px wide and 783px high or the same ration -->
                </div><!--/slide-->

                                <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/sliderimage5.jpg" width="3000" height="783" alt="Kendrick Lamar"/><!-- Replace these images with your own but make sure they are 3000px wide and 783px high or the same ration -->
                </div><!--/slide-->

                                <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/slideshow/sliderimage6.jpg" width="3000" height="783" alt="Artist Name"/><!-- Replace these images with your own but make sure they are 3000px wide and 783px high or the same ration -->
                </div><!--/slide-->



            </div><!--/slider-->
          <!--<div class="clearfix"></div>-->
        </div><!--/html_carousel-->
    </section>  <!-- Slideshow End -->

        <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://dev.mpirebooking.com"><h1 id="logotitle">MPIRE Booking</h1></a> <!-- Logo text -->
        </div><!--/logo-->

        <nav>   <!-- Navigation Start -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
                <li><a href="#footer">Contact</a></li>               
            </ul>      
        </nav>  <!-- Navigation End -->

    </div><!--/top-->
```

**Here's my CSS... (for the divs you see above)**
(Click [here](http://dev.mpirebooking.com/css/style.css) for the full style sheet)

```
#top{
    height:20px;
}

#logo {
    margin-top:1%;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

#logo a:hover { color: #8f1929; text-decoration: none; }

#logoimage{
    width:200px;
    height: 141px;
    padding-right:10px;
    float:left;
}

#logotitle{
    margin-top: 50px;
    float:right;
    font-family: Broadway, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:200%;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
}

nav ul li{
    display:block;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;  
}

nav ul li a{
    font-family:Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width:90%;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:250%;
    display:block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    color:#8f1929;
}

nav ul li p{
    font-family:Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width:90%;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:400;
    line-height:250%;
    display:block;
    color:#8f1929;
}

.html_carousel {
}
.html_carousel div.slide {
    position: relative;
}   
.html_carousel div.slide img {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius:15px;
}

.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

#slideshow{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:0%;
}

.clearfix {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several weird things on your code, like huge width properties such as `3000px` for slides and even `14326px` (!) on your `<div id="slider">` that leave no room for the logotitle. Please, check them all.

And the floating properties: that `float:right` div for the logotitle makes no sense. If it had room enough it would be ok with another `float:left` as it comes the last one.

Here you have an example with left-floated elements creating a horizontal inline layout: [www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5)

Comment: I see what you're talking about. It's not the size I've set my div to, but it's what's showing when I'm examining the code in Chrome. I didn't set that though. I'm lost on why that's like that.

Comment: Once I starting playing with the image sizes being rendered, I was able to get it down to where I wanted it. It's working now. [Here](http://dev.mpirebooking.com) is the link if you want to see it.

Comment: I'm glad to know it : )
Be careful with your id's. Don't use the same for two divs. And I recommend the use of float:left for the logotitle. With that it will have a proper height and the 1% margin will make effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class

```
.slide
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I did that, but the slider itself is displaying fine. The div you put deals with everything inside the class="slide", but the issue is the logoimage and logotitle on either side of it. I'm trying to get the the logoimage, slider, and logotitle to display in-line respectively.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's not working see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/3yg7Z/ - from the code you posted